# Finding packages in various states via aptitude

Tags: debian, aptitude

I'm looking for packages which have following situations :

1. Deleted but not purged
2. Installed but not configured

I tried things like

```
aptitude search '~id'
```

and

```
aptitude search "~iuA"
```

but neither worked.

Any ideas?

Update - one of the commands doesn't work -

```
[$] dpkg-query -Wf '${db:Status-Abbrev} ${Package}\n' | grep ^i[^i]

zsh: no matches found: ^i[^i]
```

any ideas if it is zsh at fault or something else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `aptitude` attempts, it's important to note that `~` doesn't mean 'look for the following flags in a package's status'. `~i` is shorthand for `~installed`, and then the **d** is interpreted as a literal **d**, that is, packages whose names contain the letter **d**. I looked through the documentation for `aptitude` (`/usr/share/doc/aptitude/html/en/index.html` on my system) for a search pattern that would satisfy your question, but I'm not sure it's possible. `~action` might get you half-way there, but I'm not sure about getting the status too.

---

An alternative to using `aptitude` is to use `dpkg-query` with `grep`.

`dpkg-query -Wf '${db:Status-Abbrev} ${Package}\n' | grep ^r`

This will search for packages that are in the *removed* state, but not purged.

`dpkg-query -Wf '${db:Status-Abbrev} ${Package}\n' | grep ^i[^i]`

This will search for packages that are marked to be *installed*, but are not completely installed. If you do not want to include packages pending on triggers, you can use `^i[ncHUF]` instead.

---

To get only the second column of output (the package name), you can use `sed`:

`dpkg-query -Wf '${db:Status-Abbrev} ${Package}\n' | sed -n 's/^r.R\?\s*//p'`

to find removed packages, and

`dpkg-query -Wf '${db:Status-Abbrev} ${Package}\n' | sed -n 's/^i[^i]R\?\s*//p'`

to find packages to be installed but not completely installed.

---

To expand on this a bit, Debian packages have two parts to their 'status':

- The *action* intended to be performed to a package. This can be to *install* a package, to *remove* a package, to *hold* a package, or to *purge* a pacakge.
- The *package status*, which describes the actual state of the package on your system.

The above `dpkg-query` invocation lists a package's action and status, one character each, proceeding the package name at the beginning of each line.

To find packages which are removed but not purged, we just search for packages with the 'remove' action: `grep ^r`. To find packages that are installed, or intended to be installed, but not configured yet, we search for packages whose *action* is *install*, but whose status is something other than *installed*: `grep ^i[^i]`.

Comment: Actually `$aptitude search "?installed" | grep "^id"` works just fine.

Comment: This is semantically different, I believe. This lists packages that are installed, but are set to be deleted. It sounds like you want it the other way around, that is, not fully installed, but set to be installed.


It's possible you can get `aptitude` to give you this output, but I have to ask if there's a reason you want to use `aptitude` in particular; it's meant to be a UI frontend for apt, whereas `dpkg-query` is meant to be a lower level interface for this information.

Answer (score 2):

Deleted but not purged is `~c` (`?config-files`).

Installed but not configured is not tracked by apt, only by dpkg. A package has two states: actual and desired. Apt only cares about the desired state. The desired state of a package that's installed but not configured is installed.

See [Dylan Frese's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/312265) for the dpkg queries.